# Include/exclude specific fields

Tags: elasticsearch

My index's documents looks like that:

```
{
        "sku": "1234567890",
        "name": "my_name",
        "lng:en_AE:name": "my_name_in_AE",
        "lng:en_AE:price": 10.99,
        "lng:en_BH:name": "my_name_in_BH",
        "lng:en_BH:price": 9.99,
        "lng:en_QA:name": "my_name_in_QA",
        "lng:en_QA:price": 8.99,
    }
```

There are two "types" of fields:

1. general/global - like `"sku"`, `"name"`.
2. language based fields, start with perfix: `lng:xx_YY:*` - like `"lng:en_AE:name"`.

A user can add his own fields, either general/global ones or language specific.

When we search for the documents, we want to get all general/global fields and one specific language fields:

```
{
  "_source": {
        "includes": [
          "lng:en_AE:*",
          "*"
        ],
    "excludes": [
        "lng:*"
    ]
  }
}
```

The query about doesn't work but my intent was the get exclude all languages different than `en_AE`. I don't know all `lng` possibilities in advance and I can't change the schema, is there a way to achieve that?The query about doesn't work but my intent was the get exclude all languages different than `en_AE`. I don't know all `lng` possibilities in advance and I can't change the schema, is there a way to achieve that?
I would like to get that as a response:

```
{
        "sku": "1234567890",
        "name": "my_name",
        "lng:en_AE:name": "my_name_in_AE",
        "lng:en_AE:price": 10.99,
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need the global fields you will have to define them because when you use the include "*" you add all the fields in the source again and the exclude removes all the language-based fields. It is not possible to apply the rule you want.

```
{
  "_source": {
    "includes": [
      "sku",
      "name",
      "lng:en_AE*"
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: "A user can add his own fields" - I don't have all fields in advance. A user can add a "my_global_field" - and I am not aware of it. I need to return all fields except those who doesn't related to the requested lng and the global fields..

Comment: "A user can add his own fields" - I don't have all fields in advance. A user can add a "my_global_field" - and I am not aware of it. I need to return all fields except those who doesn't related to the requested lng and the global fields..

Comment: As I said earlier, if you add "*" to the include, you cannot exclude any field.

Comment: I know that, it was a pseudo for what I'm looking for. I can remove the `*` from my example if it confusing